# Parameter type UnsafePointer<Void> in glDrawElements

Tags: ios, swift, opengl-es

I am trying to get my `context` (`EAGLContext`) to render in Swift; but for days I haven't been able to the function `glDrawElements` to work.

I have read a couple of similar questions here on Stackoverflow but to no avail.

My `glDrawElements` is as follows:

```
glDrawElements(GLenum(GL_TRIANGLES), GLsizei(Indices.count), GLenum(GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE), &offset)
```

I am having problem with the last parameter - ***offset***, which expects a `UnsafePointer<Void>`.

I have tried the following:

```
let offset: CConstVoidPointer = COpaquePointer(UnsafePointer<Int>(0))
```

The above no longer works, because `CConstVoidPointer` doesn't seem to be available anymore in Swift 1.2.

And:

```
var offset = UnsafePointer<Int>(other: 0)
```

The above gives a warning that I should use `bitPattern:` instead.

Although I don't believe `bitPattern:` should be used here (because the parameter expects a `Word`), I decided to give it a try according to the suggestion provided such as the following:

```
var offset = UnsafePointer<Int>(bitPattern: 0)
glDrawElements(GLenum(GL_TRIANGLES), GLsizei(Indices.count), GLenum(GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE), &offset)
```

I would get a `EXE_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_I386_GPFLT)` error.

In vain, I also tried something as simple as the following using:

```
var offsetZero : Int = 0
```

and subsequently feeding it to the last parameter of `glDrawElements` like so:

```
glDrawElements(GLenum(GL_TRIANGLES), GLsizei(Indices.count), GLenum(GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE), &offsetZero)
```

I am getting the same `EXE_BAD_ACCESS` like in the case above.

How can I properly form a type suitable for the last parameter of `glDrawElements` that expects the type `UnsafePointer<Void>`?

---

@RobMayoff

***Update*** (adding code for VBO set-up and variables declarations and definitions):

```
struct vertex
{
    var position: (CFloat, CFloat, CFloat)
    var color: (CFloat, CFloat, CFloat, CFloat)
}

var vertices =
[
    vertex(position: (-1, -1, 0) , color: (1, 1, 0, 1)),
    vertex(position: (1, -1, 0)  , color: (1, 1, 1, 1)),
    vertex(position: (-1, 0, 1) , color: (0, 1, 0, 1)),
    vertex(position: (-1, 1, 1), color: (1, 0, 0, 1))
]

let indices: [UInt8] = [ 0, 2, 3, 3, 1, 0 ]

class mainGLView : UIView
{
    var layer : CAEAGLLayer!
    var context : EAGLContext!
    var cBuffer : GLuint = GLuint()
    var pos : GLuint = GLuint()
    var color : GLuint = GLuint()
    var iBuffer : GLuint = GLuint()
    var vBuffer : GLuint = GLuint()
    var vao : GLuint = GLuint()

    override class func layerClass() -> AnyClass 
    {  
        return CAEAGLLayer.self
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)
    {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

       //setting up context, buffers, shaders, etc.

        self.configureVBO()
        self.setupRendering()
    }

    func configureVBO()
    {

        glGenVertexArraysOES(1, &vao);
        glBindVertexArrayOES(vao);

        glGenBuffers(GLsizei(1), &vBuffer)
        glBindBuffer(GLenum(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER), vBuffer)
        glBufferData(GLenum(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER), vertices.size(), vertices, GLenum(GL_STATIC_DRAW))

        glEnableVertexAttribArray(pos)


        var ptr = COpaquePointer(UnsafePointer<Int>(bitPattern: 0))

        glVertexAttribPointer(GLuint(pos), GLint(3), GLenum(GL_FLOAT), GLboolean(GL_FALSE), GLsizei(sizeof(vertex)), &ptr)

        glEnableVertexAttribArray(color)

        let fColor = UnsafePointer<Int>(bitPattern: sizeof(Float) * 3)

        glVertexAttribPointer(GLuint(color), 4, GLenum(GL_FLOAT), GLboolean(GL_FALSE), GLsizei(sizeof(vertex)), fColor)

        glGenBuffers(1, &iBuffer)
        glBindBuffer(GLenum(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER), iBuffer)
        glBufferData(GLenum(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER), indices.size(), indices, GLenum(GL_STATIC_DRAW))

        glBindBuffer(GLenum(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER), 0)
        glBindVertexArrayOES(0)
    }

    func setupRendering()
    {
        glBindVertexArrayOES(vao);
        glViewport(0, 0, GLint(self.frame.size.width), GLint(self.frame.size.height));

        indices.withUnsafeBufferPointer
        {
            (pointer : UnsafeBufferPointer<UInt8>) -> Void in
            glDrawElements(GLenum(GL_TRIANGLES), GLsizei(indices.count), GLenum(GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE), UnsafePointer<Void>(pointer.baseAddress))
            Void()
        }

        self.context.presentRenderbuffer(Int(GL_RENDERBUFFER))

        glBindVertexArrayOES(0)
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry to misuse a comment for this, but I could not find you in chat. Congrats on getting all eight Steward badges on [so]. I have made [this](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/311167/most-steward-badges-by-number-and-date) data query, the correct number for you should show up next Monday with the DB update.

Answer (score 1):

Because of your choices for the `count` and `type` arguments, the `indices` argument (the last argument) needs to be a pointer to the first element of an array, of (at least) length `Indices.count`, of unsigned bytes. This pointer needs to be converted to `UnsafePointer<Void>` in Swift.

You didn't show the declaration of your `Indices`. Let's assume it's declared like this:

```
let indices: [UInt8] = [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 ]
```

Then you can call `glDrawElements` by jumping through these hoops:

```
indices.withUnsafeBufferPointer { (pointer: UnsafeBufferPointer<UInt8>) -> Void in
    glDrawElements(GLenum(GL_TRIANGLES), GLsizei(indices.count),
        GLenum(GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE),
        UnsafePointer<Void>(pointer.baseAddress))
    Void()
}
```